# Drupal 7 : Fulltext search with or condition

Tags: solr, drupal-7, full-text-search

I have one views with exposed filter (Texonomy) and fulltext  textbox box.
When I am searching with taxonomy and fulltext both,
The view returns a result with "And" conditions.Means it's giving me result of nodes which have that taxonomy and fulltext word
But I want nodes with that taxonomy as well as nodes with full text search.

So, I want to add OR between them.

Please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Add button right arrow in view filter criteria and then click on `And/Or, Rearrange`
link.
and choose "AND" or "OR" option.

Please see this screenshot.

[image]

[image]

it may be helpful for you.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks. But with full text search this configuration does not work.

Comment: Add or in between them like the answer and repeat the filters again.